# Google Analytics Funnel Step Regular Expression Not Working

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics, analytics, goal-tracking

The first step in a funnel is going to have a dynamic ending fragment. Examples:

- http://mysite.com/invite/tickle-party
- http://mysite.com/invite/pajama-party
- http://mysite.com/invite/puppy-party

To allow for such dynamism, I provided this url for step one:

```
\invite(.*)
```

My goals work but the funnel visualization report shows 0 for everything.

I know this problem is due to the regex in the funnel step because I copied this entire goal except I replaced

```
\invite(.*)
```

with

```
/invite/puppy-party
```

When I hardcoded     `/invite/puppy-party` the funnel worked as expected.

Why is my funnel report not working with my original funnel step url parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the type of match needs to be set to Regular Expression even if you want the funnel URLs to be expressed as regex.